# ¿Qué necesito para implementar un bot de DialogFlow a EBS?

Tags: oracle

estoy haciendo un proyecto de investigación, pero me he quedado atascado al intentar aplicar mi bot hecho en DialogFlow a Oracle E-Business Suite.

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el problema edita la pregunta y muestra el codigo que tienes para bot

Comment: El problema que tengo es que he creado un bot con DialogFlow pero quiero poder acceder a Oracle E-Business Suite para hacer una consulta de stock. Adjuntaría el codigo pero son muchos archivos json. Lo que necesito los pasos teoricos para conectarlos. Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

lo que debes hacer es trabajar con los Webhook para que puedas traer informacion desde otros sistemas. Por ejemplo te puede ayudar trabajar con el Firebase de google, especificamente con los functions donde te genera un webhooj en node.js y desde aqui consultar al api que tengas del Oracle Business Suite para leer tu inventario. Y luego enviarlo por respuesta a dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás intentando acceder desde tu webhook, recuerda que las cuentas gratuitas solo pueden acceder a api's de Google, por lo que si quieres acceder a un lugar diferente puedes poner el plan blaze o de pago por uso, mientras uses pocos recursos no te cobrará, puedes consultar los precios aquí https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?hl=es-419
Ahora sí tu duda es como hacerlo, necesitas tener un webhook que es básicamente como un servicio web que recibe peticiones, las procesa y reenvía respuestas, en fulfilment puedes ver un poco más de eso.